# Access member variables/getters from comparison function

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, comparator, accessor

I'm basically trying to write comparator function to sort by x then y value of Object P1 and Pt2 in both ascending and descending order.

Now I'm having an error that x and y is protected but how do I use getters correctly in sort, please?
I'm still pretty confused. I tried to use this but doesn't work.

```
bool Line2D::sortLine2DPtAsc (const Point2D& left, const Point2D& right) 
{
    return (left.pt1.getX() < right.pt1.getX()) || ((left.pt1.getX() == right.pt1.getX()) && (left.pt1.getY() < right.pt1.getY()));
}
```

---

Error using getters:

```
Line2D.cpp:25:15: error: ‘const class Point2D’ has no member named ‘pt1’
Line2D.cpp:25:34: error: ‘const class Point2D’ has no member named ‘pt1’
Line2D.cpp:25:56: error: ‘const class Point2D’ has no member named ‘pt1’
Line2D.cpp:25:76: error: ‘const class Point2D’ has no member named ‘pt1’
Line2D.cpp:25:97: error: ‘const class Point2D’ has no member named ‘pt1’
Line2D.cpp:25:116: error: ‘const class Point2D’ has no member named ‘pt1’
```

---

here's my code:

```
class Line2D
{

    private:    
        Point2D pt1;
        Point2D pt2;

    public:
        //Constructor
        Line2D ();
        Line2D (Point2D pt1, Point2D pt2);

        //Accessors
        Point2D getPt1();
        Point2D getPt2();
        double getScalarValue();    //returns the value of attribute length

        //Mutators
        void setPt1 (Point2D pt1);
        void setPt2 (Point2D pt2);

        static bool sortLine2DPtAsc (const Point2D& left, const Point2D& right) ;
}


bool Line2D::sortLine2DPtAsc (const Point2D& left, const Point2D& right) 
{
    return (left.x < right.x) || ((left.x == right.x) && (left.y < right.y));
}
```

Comment: Today is apparently the day of ambiguous "it doesn't work" questions, with no elaboration of *what that means*. Doesn't compile? Doesn't sort like you want? Hangs? Crashes? I 'm betting Paul's answer is correct, and you should take a look at it. And please be more specific, particularly if it is a compiler or runtime **error** message, in which case include the *entire* message *verbatim* with your question.

Comment: There you go. Excellent message post. So can I ask what is potentially an embarrassing question? What collection of *points* are you sorting? Unless I'm mistaken, you're sorting a collection of `Line2D` objects, right? Each of which has two points? that would explain quite a lot.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have amended to bool Line2D::sortLine2DPtAsc (const Line2D& left, const Line2D& right) and managed to compile successfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the version with the getters, but replace `left.pt1.getX()` with `left.getX()`, etc.

And I'm guessing that in your `Point2D` class, you need to change

```
double getX();
```

to

```
double getX() const;
```

And likewise for `getY`.

Being passed `const Point2D& left, const Point2D& right`, you are under contract not to modify any values in those objects. You can only call their members functions that are declared `const` (they will not change the object).

Comment: You can further assume `getY()` is in a similar predicament.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious, +1.

Comment: See the updated code in the post, and the error message. never would have seen *that* coming.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I updated my answer. Thanks for requesting clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`bool Line2D::sortLine2DPtAsc (const Point2D& left, const Point2D& right)`
your parameters are of type `Point2D`, maybe you meant to have them of type `Line2D`
if the function is sorting lines, why are you passing it points ;) 
`pt1` and `pt2` are members of the `Line2D` class not the your `Point2D` class